# grails: testing 'sort' mapping in a domain class

Tags: sorting, grails, testing, mapping, grails-orm

Given the example from [grails doc](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/GORM.html#defaultSortOrder):

```
class Airport {
    …
    static hasMany = [flights: Flight]
    static mapping = {
        flights sort: 'number', order: 'desc'
    }
}
```

How can one test sorting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated in the docs, it does not work like written. You have to add `static belongsTo = [airport:Airport]` to Flight.

Without belongsTo you get the following error:

Default sort for associations [Airport->flights] are not supported with unidirectional one to many relationships.

With belongsTo the test could look like this:

```
class SortSpec extends IntegrationSpec {
    def "test grails does sort flights" () {
        given:
        def airport = new Airport()
        airport.addToFlights (new Flight (number: "A"))
        airport.addToFlights (new Flight (number: "C"))
        airport.addToFlights (new Flight (number: "B"))
        airport.save (failOnError: true, flush:true)

        when:
        def sortedAirport = airport.refresh() // reload from db to apply sorting

        then:
        sortedAirport.flights.collect { it.number } == ['C', 'B', 'A']
    }
}
```

But.. it doesn't make much sense to write a test like this because it checks that grails applies the sorting configuration. Why would I want to test grails? Test *your* code and not the framework.

Comment: I've been using a different syntax to populate the collection:

          airport.flights = [ new Flight (number: "C"), 
                              new Flight (number: "A"), 
                              new Flight (number: "B")]

This actually fails the test. How is it different to .addToFlights()?

Comment: The difference between using addTo* and directly assigning the collection is that addTo* automatically sets the belongsTo reference (in the added object) while the assignment does not.

Answer (score 0):

For sorting in case of association, simply do the following:

```
class UserProjectInvolvement {
Project project

 static mapping = {
    sort 'project.name'
 }
}
```

I am using 2.4.4 and it is working perfectly.